# Shader doesn't affect entire Object

Tags: materials, objects

Why does the the shader color not affect the entire object and why does it produce a gap?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have no idea how to decode your question. Please explain more thoroughly

Comment: I concur with @alexanderesmith, you need to clarify if you want a chance to get help.

Comment: I see your question ("Why doesn't the object take the color?"), but I see that the object is transparent, and red. Were you expecting something else?

Comment: there is a gap if you look at second picture,and red color only in the top and locks like a dome.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification :D

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Welcome to the plattform. Please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
Maybe we can help you if you puth together a few thouroughly thought of sentences like trying to explain your goal, what you have tried getting there, and the things you are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the reflection of the table. Try hiding the table/plane object and take a look.

**Edit to address followup question;**

... Technically, yes, you can disable the table in the reflection. Start by switching to the Cycles rendering engine (and make sure GPU is selected if you have a GPU capable of supporting Cycles);

[image]

In the Object Properties, Under Visibility -> Ray visibility, uncheck "Glossy";

[image]

The result;

[image]

It should be noted, though, that this will produce a highly unrealistic result in your final scene.

Comment: yeah its work, but can i cancel that ??, thank you.

Comment: See my updated answer